# redirect back to job_seeker.register

Tags: laravel-5.8, laravel-authentication

im new to laravel 5.8 im trying to set up a multiple auth but after i register a new job_seeker it suppose to redirect me to job_seeker.profile instead it redirect me back to job_seeker.register

i try some code in stackoverflow but nothing works

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }




protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {

        if ($request->expectsJson())
        {
            return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
        }

        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);

        switch ($guard) {
            case 'job_seeker':
                $login = 'job_seeker.register';
                break;

            case 'employer':
                $login = 'employer.register';
                break;

            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }


 Route::post('job_seeker.login',['as'=>'job_seeker.login','uses'=>'job_seeker\login_job_seeker_Controller@login']);
        Route::get('job_seeker.register',['as'=>'job_seeker.register','uses'=>'job_seeker\login_job_seeker_Controller@show_login_form']);
        Route::get('job_seeker.profile',['as'=>'job_seeker.profile','uses'=>'job_seeker\job_seeker_profile_controller@show_profile']);
```

Comment: Why are there two unauthenticated functions? Try removing the first one and run again.

Comment: Ujawal Kandrya the first one is for the auth middleware i remove it but the i had the same probelm when i delete the other in handler i have been redirected to login which i want to beredirected to job_seeker.regsiter

Comment: You may have to do same thing in your RedirectIfAuthenticated.php file.